# Contour Integral Stein Chapter3 Question5

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am trying to solve the following problem, taken from "Stein-Shakarchi's Complex Analysis" Chapter 3 Question 5: Show that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2\pi i x\epsilon}}{(1+x^2)^2}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}(1 + 2 \pi |\epsilon|)e^{-2\pi|\epsilon|}$$ for all $\epsilon$ real.

**My Attempt:**

**STEP1:** I define $f(z):= \frac{e^{-2\pi i z\epsilon}}{(1+z^2)^2}$ and choose the contour $\gamma$, the semi-cirle or radius $R$ in the lower half-plane. More precisely, $\gamma:= \{z \in \mathbb{C}: z = Re^{i \theta}, \theta \in [\pi , 2\pi] \} \cup [-R,R]$.

**STEP2:** Clearly, $f(z)$ is a meromorphic function, which has a pole of order $2$ at $z = -i$ inside $\gamma$. As a result, using *residue theorem*, we have: $$\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz = 2\pi i \, \text{res}_{-i}f$$

**STEP3:** Let's compute the residue:
\begin{align}
\text{res}_{-i}f = lim_{z \rightarrow -i}(\frac{d}{dz})(z+i)^2f(z) \\
= lim_{z \rightarrow -i} \frac{-2\pi i \epsilon \, e^{-2 \pi i z \epsilon} (z-i)^2 - 2(z-i)e^{-2 \pi i z \epsilon}}{(z-i)^4} \\
= e^{-2 \pi \epsilon} [\frac{2 \pi i \epsilon + i}{4}]
\end{align}

**STEP4:** Thus, the integral is equal to $\pi i \, e^{-2 \pi \epsilon} [\frac{2 \pi i \epsilon + i}{2}]$.

**STEP5:** The integral is equal to $$\int_{R}^{-R}\frac{e^{-2\pi i x\epsilon}}{(1+x^2)^2}dx + \int_{\gamma_R}f(z)dz .$$

The second part goes to $0$ as $R$ goes to $\infty$. Letting $R$ goes to $\infty$, we get $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2\pi i x\epsilon}}{(1+x^2)^2}dx = -\pi i \, e^{-2 \pi \epsilon} [\frac{2 \pi i \epsilon + i}{2}].$$ Thus, my result does not match the result in the book. Can you point my mistake(s), please?

Comment: You should use the upper half plane, because the integral along your $\gamma_R$ does not converge to $0$.

Comment: @Riemann, haa I guess my problem is the following: If $\epsilon$ is positive, then I should use the lower half plane, if $\epsilon$ is negative, then I should use the upper half plane, so that the integral on the circle goes to $0$ ?

Comment: Your analysis is fine for $\varepsilon>0$.